# Python core application

Tags: python, background, exec

I'm new to Python and I'm writing a script that
includes some timed routines. 
My current approach is to instantiate a class
that includes those Timers (from: threading.Timer),
but I don't want the script to return when it gets to the
end of the function:

```
import mytimer

timer = mytimer()
```

Suppose I have a imple script like that one. All it
does is instantiate a mytimer object which performs a series
of timed activities.

In order for the application not to exit, I could use Qt like this:

```
from PyQt4.QtCore import QCoreApplication
import mytimer
import sys

def main():
    app = QCoreApplication(sys.argv)
    timer = mytimer()

    sys.exit(app.exec_())

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

This way, the *sys.exit()* call won't return immediately, and the 
timer would just keep doing its thing 'forever' in background.

Although  this is a solution I've used before, using Qt just for this doesn't
fell right to me.
So my question is, Is there any way to accomplish this using standard Python?

Thanks

Comment: As soon as you use an external framework, you're *not* in "standard" Python. When in Rome, do as the Romans.

Comment: Exactly, that why I'm asking for a way to do this using standard Python.

Comment: I would use threads and signals/slots for this.

Comment: The need for Signal/Slot functionality in this application is not evident to me. Could you please elaborate on this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a function in your script which tests a [select or poll object](http://docs.python.org/library/select.html#poll-objects) to terminate a loop. Check out `serve_forever` in [`SocketServer.py`](http://svn.python.org/projects/python/branches/release25-maint/Lib/SocketServer.py) from the standard library as an example.

Comment: Hi, thank you for your answer. I'm looking for a more straightforward way to do this. I think the Qt solution is more Pythonic in a way...

Answer (score 0):

A Google search for "python timer" finds:

http://docs.python.org/library/sched.html

http://docs.python.org/release/2.5.2/lib/timer-objects.html

The `sched` module seems to be exactly what you need.

Example:

```
>>> import sched, time
>>> s = sched.scheduler(time.time, time.sleep)
>>> def print_time(): print "From print_time", time.time()
...
>>> def print_some_times():
...     print time.time()
...     s.enter(5, 1, print_time, ())
...     s.enter(10, 1, print_time, ())
...     s.run()
...     print time.time()
...
>>> print_some_times()
930343690.257
From print_time 930343695.274
From print_time 930343700.273
930343700.276
```

Once you have built your queue of times for things to happen, you just call the `.run()` method on your `sched` instance, and it will automatically wait until the queue is emptied, then will complete.  So you can just put `s.run()` as the last thing in your script, and it will automatically exit only when the timed tasks are all done.

Comment: Hi, thank you for your answer. For my application, I need the timer(s) inside `mytimer` to run indefinitely, 'forever'. The QCoreApplication still seems more natural.

Comment: `s.run()` will not stop until the last task is done.  If you keep adding tasks to the queue at regular intervals, it will never stop.  It is explicitly allowed for the function called by the timer to modify the queue, for example to place another task for the future.

Answer (score 0):

```
import mytimer
import sys

from threading import Lock

lock = Lock()
lock.acquire() # put lock into locked state

def main():
    timer = mytimer()

    lock.acquire()  # blocks until someone calls lock.release()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

If you want a clean exit, you can just make `mytimer()` call `lock.release()` at some point.

Comment: I like this solution. So the QCoreApplication object won't be necessary?

Comment: Correct; I just copied your code and failed to remove that line.  I'll remove it now.